# Where is the code for correlation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with anaconda and looking for the code for the correlation matrix in pandas.
I look into `/pandas/core/frame.py` and found

```
from pandas._libs import algos as libalgos, lib, properties
```

several lines after I found:

```
def corr(self, method="pearson", min_periods=1) -> "DataFrame":
```

this uses `correl` from `libalgos`

```
if method == "pearson":
    correl = libalgos.nancorr(mat, minp=min_periods)
```

But when I look in `../pandas/lib/`
there is not `algos` library.

My question is the `libalgos.nacorr` is compiled in `C` and where is the code.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is in the `DataFrame` class. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html

```
DataFrame.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
```

If you are looking for the actual nancorr source, see here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d4cd068ae278d2a37788363df48f687ee1baceba/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx

Comment: I think that they know this, and are trying to find the actual implementation of that method.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer to take this into account

Comment: Thanks, I saw : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d4cd068ae278d2a37788363df48f687ee1baceba/pandas/_libs/algos.pyx

share  edit  follow